# Unmarshalling exception while creating a Service object

Tags: kubernetes, service, google-kubernetes-engine

Below is my Service object

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: srv1
spec:
  selector:
    name: srv1
  ports:
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 9736
```

When I am creating this object then I get below exception, do anyone knows what is wrong in this?

`Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "listing62.yaml": Service in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Service: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field ServiceSpec.spec.ports of type []v1.ServicePort`

I have tried to make changes to the service object but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the problem:

`protocol: TCP`

You are missing a hyphen. You need to put:

`- protocol: TCP`

Basically, if there is a list for a specific field (like, containers, ports), then commonly, there is a hyphen at the start.

Answer (score 0):

Try you are missing **-** in `ports []`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: srv1
spec:
  selector:
    name: srv1
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9376
```